# Oracle-Apex create page as copy

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to change page number, I decided to create page as copy, after creation copy page, that page doesn't have same functionality like original page. All in page is same, dynamic action, process, sql query...

Why copied page doesn't have same functionality?

I hope I've explained well.
I tried to find similar question on stack, but I didn't find.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I remember, older Apex versions (which one do you use?) would "ignore" page number change in PL/SQL units. For example, if your query used

```
select empno, ename
from emp
where deptno = :P1_DEPTNO
```

and you copied it to a new page (e.g. number 2), query would still be the same, referencing `:P1_DEPTNO` instead of `:P2_DEPTNO`.

Also, if the "original" page was called from some other page which passed some items' values to it, the "copied" page doesn't have that functionality - you'd have to manually modify the "caller" page and switch `P1_` items to `P2_`.

Other than that ... I can't remember anything else. Generally speaking, it *should* work.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Apex change item name in my case add  11_ (11 is page number), I forgot to check items name :)